# Advice on research ideas on Non Linear Dynamics

Tags: soft-question, ds.dynamical-systems, advice, chaos

I am interested in Non Linear Dynamics.

I am just a beginner to this research area in the sense that I am starting to read the research papers.

My aim is to make my project to a research paper.

But I am unable to find an idea for the research project.Like a topic on which I should work on and appreciate it as a beginner student.

So it would be great and helpful if you could cite some research ideas or projects or reference papers on which I can carry this research project.

I am interested and curious to know  different user's opinion on which I should work as a starting researcher on Non-Linear Dynamics.

Knowledge on Non Linear Dynamics - 
I have read the basics of Non Linear dynamics from Prof.Steven Strogatz book also have seen the video lectures given by him.